# All possible combination of different arrays item, different sizes in a new array

Tags: javascript

```
color = [
    [blue],
    [yellow], 
    [red]
];
```

```
size = [
    [big],
    [medium], 
    [small],
    [very small]
];
```

I want to get the different combination in a new array by using the data in the other arrays.

```
balloons = [
    [blue, big],
    [red, big],
    ...
];
```

What should I use so I wont get [blue, big] and [big, blue] in the array balloons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 nested `for`-loops. I assume that you mean `'blue'` instead of `[blue]`.

```js
let color = ['blue','yellow', 'red'];
let size = ['big','medium','small','very small'];
let result = [];

for (let i=0; i<color.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<size.length; j++) {
        result.push([color[i],size[j]]);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

is this your expectation?

```js
const color = [["blue"], ["yellow"], ["red"]];
const size = [["big"], ["medium"], ["small"], ["verysmall"]];
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < size.length; j++) {
    result.push([...color[i], ...size[j]]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two nested `forEach` loops to do this:

```js
const colors = ["blue", "yellow", "red"];
const sizes = ["big", "medium", "small", "very small"];

const out = [];

colors.forEach(color =>
  sizes.forEach(size =>
    out.push([color, size])
  )
)

console.log(out)
```